# Plantilla handlebars no se rellena incluso cuando hay datos

Tags: revisión-de-código, kotlin

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Kotlin que genera ficheros XML usando plantillas con Handlebars (en el [lado del servidor](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java), la versión 4.0.6). Tengo la siguiente clase en un fichero .kt:

```
class miClase(val codigo: String, val nombre: String?)
```

Y esto en una plantilla .hbs:

```
...
{{#each misClases}}
  <elemento code="{{codigo}}" name="{{nombre}}">
{{/each}}
...
```

Y funciona sin problemas. El XML se genera con una lista de elementos. Ahora me han pedido que la parte de la plantilla que se genera a partir de una lista de `miClase` no debe incluir elementos vacíos. Es decir, si falta el código o el nombre, se mostrará, pero si faltan los dos, no se mostrarán.

Para eso he cambiado la clase a esto:

```
class miClase(val codigo: String, val nombre: String?) {

    var isVisible = true

    init {
        if (codigo.isNullOrEmpty() && nombre.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            isVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

Y la plantilla la he cambiado para que sea así:

```
...
{{#each misClases}}
  {{#if isVisible}}
  <elemento code="{{codigo}}" name="{{nombre}}">
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
...
```

Todo parece correcto, pero los datos no se muestran. He hecho debug, y puedo ver que la lista de objetos está ahí y que todos tienen la propiedad `isVisible` con el valor `true` por lo que esa parte de la plantilla debería rellenarse y estar visible, pero no lo está.

Lo que ocurre no es que los valores aparezcan vacíos, sino que directamente ni siquiera se carga el `elemento`.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Qué es lo que falla en el código?

Comment: ¿Cual versión de handlebars usas?

Comment: Otra pregunta: ¿qué XML genera exactamente? ¿Genera `<elemento code="" name="">` con los 2 atributos vacíos, o ni siquiera aparece el tag `elemento`?

Comment: @sstan he actualizado la pregunta para reflejar lo que pedías. La versión es la 4.0.6, y ni siquiera aparee el tag elemento.

Comment: Hmm, no pude reproducir tu error con un ejemplo simplificado. Todo me funcionó como debería. Todo se ve bien. Lo siento.

Comment: @sstan al final lo he podido solucionar de la manera más rara/tonta: cambiando el nombre de la propiedad de `isVisible` a `hasCodeName` y ya funciona. Parece como si `isVisible` fuera una palabra reservada o algo, pero no encuentro nada en la documentación al respecto

Comment: No tendrá nada que ver con el error tipográfico en el cierre del `if`?

Comment: @amenadiel No. ese fallo se debe a que escribí el código a mano para evitar poner código propiedad de la empresa. El problema se solucionó simplemente cambiando el nombre de la variable

Comment: @sstan ¿lo probaste con Kotlin y Handlebars en el servidor? No encuentro referencia en mi código a `isVisible`

Comment: No, mi prueba en realidad no fue exactamente como el tuyo. Yo lo hize con Javascript + handlebars en el cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he podido solucionar de la manera más rara/tonta: cambiando el nombre de la propiedad de `isVisible` a `hasCodeName` (aunque valdría otro nombre) y ya funciona.

Parece que `isVisible` es una palabra reservada o un método en alguno de los plugins y dependencias que usa el proyecto (en particular parece que de Selenium). Entonces no tomaba el `isVisible` de la clase, sino el `isVisible` de la dependencia y por eso fallaba. Cambiar el nombre fue la solución.